# Immutable field/cell in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, relational-theory

Is there a way to create an immutable field/cell in a Postgres record? AKA, only allow the field to be written once, perhaps just on insert?

Use case: I have a "uuid" field for a record, and it should never ever be changed (same with the PK as well).

Comment: Trigger, which detects the attempt to alter the value and reverts it. For example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several techniques for that:

- Using column permissions, grant `UPDATE` only on the other columns.
- Create an `UPDATE` trigger that throws an exception when `OLD.id <> NEW.id`.

Note that all these measures can never deny the table owner access, since the owner can always change permissionsand drop triggers.

Comment: is there a way to blacklist updates instead of whitelisting them with "grant UPDATE"

Comment: No, permissions are always additive.

Comment: hmm with the exception that by default updating every field is ok?

Comment: No, it isn't. You have to explicitly grant `UPDATE` on the table, which implies the right to update all columns. You have to revoke that if you want to use column permissions, then grant `UPDATE` only on the desired columns.